# Inserting dates before year 1950 in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-9i

How can I insert date which is before 1950?

```
update up_sif.tb_person set dateB =to_date('18.10.1949','DD.MM.YYYY') where ID = '123345';
```

It keeps update with date 18.19.2049.

Any ideas?

Comment: If that is the statement you are running, the year will be 1949 (I'm assuming that the 19 in 18.19 is a typo).  What makes you believe that the year is 2049?  Are you sure that your actual `UPDATE` statement isn't using the `RR` format mask?  Or that you're using the `RR` format mask to display the data?

Comment: Yes 19 is a typo. It updates with 18.10.2049. I also tried to set NLS_DATE_FORMAT (ALTER SESSION set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY';) but there's no effect.

Comment: What makes you believe that the year is 2049?  Post a complete, reproducible test case that shows us exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: What does `SELECT TO_CHAR(dateB, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM up_sif.tb_person WHERE id = '123345' ;` show?

Comment: You should also learn about *date constants*. These are specified as `date 'YYY-MM-DD'`, so your update statement can be shortened/simplified to `update up_sif.tb_person set dateB = date '1949-10-18' where ID = '123345';`. In addition, date constants use the ISO standard date format, which is a good practice to be following.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

create table date_
(
date_ date
);

insert into date_
values(to_date('20130331','YYYYMMDD'))

commit;

update date_
set date_=to_date('19491018','YYYYMMDD')
commit;

Comment: Learn about *date constants*, please.